# Typescript check variable null or undefined

Tags: typescript

Sorry not sure how to describe my question. Hope the title does not mislead you.

First of all, my issue happens in Angular 11 with strict mode turned on.

Suppose I have an array

```
let results: T[] = [];
```

and I have a function as follow and this function does not give any error in Visual Studio Code.

```
filter = (values: (T | null | undefined)[]): T[] => {
  for(let value of values) {
    if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
      results.push(value);
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I extract the condition to another function, such as

```
isNullOrUndefined = (value: T | null | undefined): bool => {
  return value === null || value === undefined;
}
```

and then use the function in the above `filter` function as follow:

```
filter = (values: (T | null | undefined)[]): T[] => {
  for(let value of values) {
    if (!isNullOrUndefined(value)) {
      results.push(value);
    }
  }
}
```

I get an error `Argument of type 'Nullable<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.`

Can anyone please help to have a look? Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with the typing of the `isNullOrUndefined` function.

When you use the condition like this

```
if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
     results.push(value); // value is only T here
```

it is used as a type constrain. Typescript automatically constrains the type
of value in the `if` branch to `T`.

But if you use `isNullOrUndefined` which returns `boolean`, Typescript does not check
the actual implementation of the function - even if you did not specify the return type
explicitly.

```
if (!isNullOrUndefined(value)) {
  results.push(value); // value still is T | null | undefined
}
```

In order to make it work, you need to type the `isNullOrUndefined` as a type contrain as well by specifying the return type as `value is null | undefined`

```
isNullOrUndefined = (value: T | null | undefined): value is null | undefined => {
  return value === null || value === undefined;
}
```

Then Typescript will behave the same as with the original version.

```
if (!isNullOrUndefined(value)) {
  results.push(value); // value is T
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the logic be reversed? Not an expert on Type Guards, but this seems to imply that both null and undefined are T.

Answer (score -1):

A short way is

> let show = !input ? false : true;

```
let input = null;
let show = !input ? false : true;
console.log("show: " + input + " --> " + show);

input = undefined;
show = !input ? false : true;
console.log("show: " + input + " --> "  + show);

input = false;
show = !input ? false : true;
console.log("show: " + input + " --> "  + show);

input= true;
show = !input ? false : true;
console.log("show: " + input + " --> "  + show);
```

returns

```
show: null --> false
show: undefined --> false
show: false --> false
show: true --> true
```